# Difference between $object->attribute and $object['attribute'] in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent

I'm developing with DataTables in Laravel and trying to make an object manually using `collect()` to create a collection. When I push the collection into the DataTable, there is something wrong, and I can't call my object with this `$object->attribute.`

After I get the error with that, I already tried to call an attribute with `$object['attribute'],` and it works well.

Can someone give me insight about the differences and how I can convert `$object['attribute']` into `$object->attribute`?

This is my query to create object

```
$result = collect();
$item = collect([
         'row' => ($key+1),
         'item_id' => $value->uid,
         'item' => $value->nama_item,
         'sub_kategori' => $value->sub_jenis_item->sub_jenis_item,
         'kategori' => $value->jenis_item->jenis_item,
         'gudang_id' => $id_gudang
]);
$result->push($item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `$object['attribute']` means `$object` is an `array` and accessing `$object->attribute` means `$object` is an `object`.

To convert `array` to `object`:

```php
$object = (object) $object;
```

Additionally, to convert `object` to `array`:

```php
$object = (array) $object;
```

Comment: I tried that and still can't access $object->attribute

Answer (score 0):

DataTables calls internally `toArray()` on the collection items when you build the table. This happens during [transformation](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/177b4360031ba1e7c040622b12cfd563d33274c6/src/Utilities/Helper.php#L171-L203) of the data. It will also flatten nested objects (e.g. loaded Eloquent relations in case of an `EloquentDataTable`) into an array with depth 1 (per row of the table).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way,

```
   $result = collect();
    $item = collect([
        'row' => ($key+1),
        'item_id' => $value->uid,
        'item' => $value->nama_item,
        'sub_kategori' => $value->sub_jenis_item->sub_jenis_item,
        'kategori' => $value->jenis_item->jenis_item,
        'gudang_id' => $id_gudang
     ]
    );
    $result->push($item);

    $resultObj = json_decode($result);

    foreach($resultObj as $obj){
        echo $obj->row;
    }
```